# Convert a string with date and time to a date

Tags: python, datetime

I've got this date time string:

```
post["date"] = "2007-07-18 10:03:19"
```

I'd like to extract just "2007-07-18" as a date. I've seen some reference to `strptime` but I'm not sure how to use it.  How can I extract the date from this string?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The other two answers are fine, but if you actually want the date for something else, you can use the `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime('2007-07-18 10:03:19', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
day_string = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

It might be overkill for now, but it'll come in useful. You can see all of the format specifiers [here](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime).

Comment: can u plz tell me the format of "Wed Dec 17 14:58:39 IST 2014" ?

Comment: @DinoopNair this should be the format you are looking for: "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"

Answer (score 8):

In your case, just use split:

```
>>> d1="2007-07-18 10:03:19"
>>> d1.split()[0]
'2007-07-18'
>>>
```

(The 1st part after splitting with whitespace)

If you insist on using `strptime`, the format is `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` :

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strptime(d1,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
time.struct_time(tm_year=2007, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=18, tm_hour=10, tm_min=3, tm_sec=19, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=199, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", _)
'2007-07-18'
>>>
```

Comment: to avoid IndexError for empty data, you could use `d1.partition(' ')[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Probably not what you are looking for but you could just split the string:

```
post["date"].split()[0]
```

would give you `'2007-07-18'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil which can support any datetime format e.g:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> d1="2007-07-18 10:03:19"
>>> date_obj = parse(d1)
>>> date_obj
datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 18, 10, 3, 19)
>>> date_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2007-07-18'
>>> d2 = "18-07-2007 10:03:19"
>>> d = parse(d2)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 18, 10, 3, 19)
>>> d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2007-07-18'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mx.DateTime` module from [eGenix](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/)

```
import mx

date_object = mx.DateTime.Parser.DateTimeFromString('2007-07-18 10:03:19')
print "%s-%s-%s" % (date_object.year, date_object.month, date_object.day)
```

will output: `2007-07-18`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [parsedatetime](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsedatetime/) module.

```
>>> from parsedatetime.parsedatetime import Calendar
>>> c = Calendar()
>>> c.parse("2007-07-18 10:03:19")
((2008, 11, 19, 10, 3, 19, 2, 324, 0), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import dateutil.parser
a = "2007-07-18 10:03:19"
d = dateutil.parser.parse(b).date()
```

Your Output will be like this
**

> datetime.date(2007, 07, 18)

**