# Converting a month's name to its corresponding number

Tags: python, date

I have a file which contains a list of entries, with dates that contain "Jan","Feb","Mar" etc.

I want

> 569207,ngph,RUN,512,16,**2012-Jan-23 01:42**,2012-04-23 10:53

to become

> 569207,ngph,RUN,512,16,**2012-01-23 01:42**,2012-04-23 10:53.

I've written the following:

```
   for line in f:
        if re.search(r'Jan', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('Jan', '01'))
        elif re.search(r'Feb', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('Feb', '02'))
        elif re.search(r'Mar', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('Mar', '03'))
        elif re.search(r'Apr', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('Apr', '04'))
        elif re.search(r'May', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('May', '05'))
        elif re.search(r'Jun', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('Jun', '06'))
        elif re.search(r'Jul', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('Jul', '07'))
        elif re.search(r'Aug', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('Aug', '08'))
        elif re.search(r'Sep', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('Sep', '09'))
        elif re.search(r'Oct', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('Oct', '10'))
        elif re.search(r'Nov', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('Nov', '11'))
        elif re.search(r'Dec', line):
            f1.write(line.replace('Dec', '12'))
```

which works, but is there a cleaner method? I want it to iterate through an entire file of about 100 lines and automatically change the month to a number. Thanks.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301528/how-to-convert-a-date-in-python

Comment: Should have mentioned, I want it to iterate through an entire file of about 100 lines and automatically change the month to a number.

Comment: right, but that's a different question, no? It's probably better to keep your SO questions about date manipulation and your questions about file IO separate, it leads to more flexible solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module
2. DIY solution like you have

The python documentation is worth reading, you may find an easier way to do more than just answer this question.

As for the DIY solution it seems like you have a lot of repeat code, and there's no need for a regex. You could just do

```
for i, month in enumerate(months,1): 
    line.replace(month, str(i))
```

where `months` is a list of the months.

Comment: Datetime is locale-aware, so it is a much better solution.

Answer (score 11):

datetime is the answer, for example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('Mar 2013',"%b %Y")
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 1, 0, 0)
```

Check the format directives at http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use dictionary:

```
month_numbers = {'-Jan-': '-01-', '-Feb-': '-02-', ...}
for k, v in month_numbers.items():
    line = line.replace(k, v)
print(line)
```

You use regexpes where you can use simple string `replace()` method without first checking if month name is in the string. I don't know if string `Jan` can be in other part of the input string, but IMO it is safer to replace `-Jan-` to `-01-`.