# Converting Twitter's date format to Datetime in python

Tags: python-2.7

date time format returned by `Twitter` is in this form:

```
Thu Apr 23 13:38:19 +0000 2009
```

I want it in `datetime` format for database enty and query...

Comment: To which database? You would be running a query to insert it, wouldnt you? Try the inbuilt functions in your DB.

Comment: but i need python implementation because i want use it as a checking condition in my code...help appriciated

Answer (score 8):

EDIT - 13 Apr 15
As suggested, please use.

```
 datetime.strptime('Thu Apr 23 13:38:19 +0000 2009','%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y').replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```

Now, if you want work much on the Date parsing and playing around with Date Time strings, use [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) or [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

---

Please ignore the suggestion below

I have not been working much on Python lately, but this should do the trick.

```
>>>from datetime import datetime
>>>d = datetime.strptime('Thu Apr 23 13:38:19 +0000 2009','%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y');
>>>print d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
```

This is based on [Python Doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301528/how-to-convert-a-date-in-python)

Comment: `%z` doesn'twork. Need to instead use `datetime.strptime('Thu Apr 23 13:38:19 +0000 2009','%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y').replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is stored in a data frame "df" and the time for the tweet is stored in the "created_at" column. you can do:

```
df["created_at"] = df["created_at"].astype('datetime64[ns]') 
df["created_at"] = df.created_at.dt.to_pydatetime()
```

Comment: This is especially useful for correcting the presence of T and Z is tweets pulled using Twitter API v2.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple for those looking for unix time, working great in 2023

```
created_at="Sat May 26 09:56:04 +0000 2018"
unix_timestamp=time.mktime(time.strptime(created_at,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'))
print(unix_timestamp)
```

Output: 1527342964.0